# Working with editable table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-data-list

My code edits a table cell by clicking on it. But I want to add a datalist to make it easier. It should be something like an autocomplete text. Can I add a datalist to this code? I want to see the datalist when I do edits on the names.

```
<td title="Workername">
<div id ="datalist" onclick="makeElementEditable(this)" 
onblur="updateWorkers(this,'<?php echo $row['taskid'] ?>')"> 
<?php echo $row['name'];  ?></div>


              <datalist id="datalist">
                <option value="test2">
                <option value="test3">
                <option value="test4">
                <option value="test5">
                <option value="test">
              </datalist>
       </td>
```

To make element editable:

```
function makeElementEditable(div){
    div.style.border = "1px solid lavender";
    div.style.padding = "5px";
    div.style.background = "white";
    div.contentEditable = true;
}
```

So what are your suggestions?

Comment: Are you open to using datatables?

Comment: I use tables and I edit the information on table cells dynamically. All I need is to add autocomplete boxes when I edit the information.